# Running Robot Framework tests with VirtualBox and IE11

Tags: virtualbox, internet-explorer-11, robotframework

I'm a Linux user, but I have a need to run my Robot Framework tests with IE11. I have set up Virtual Box with Win7 + IE11. I set up system and run below test there:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
*** Test Cases ***
Run a browser
   Open Browser    http://www.google.com    ie    None    http://192.168.56.101:4444/wd/hub
```

Now in virtual machine IE is opened and www.google.com page is opened. So this simple test is working fine.

I'm just wondering, what would be best way for me to run actual tests in virtual machine. I have a lot of tests. Can I somehow give address http://192.168.56.101:4444/wd/hub to command line somehow with start command?

Or do I have to make special keyword to check, how to start testing.

Any suggestions? How have you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using robot framework, you can declare this information in the command line using the appropriate arguments.  An example of this could be formatted like:

robot --include smoke --variable HOST:[host_IP] path/to/tests/

This information can be found in more detail here:
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id142